# Calling a URL from the Address Bar

Tags: php, url, frame

I'm working on a link cloaker, and one of the features is the "Add This" social bookmark widget.  It gives you the opportunity to define the URL that will be shared with this code:

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style " addthis:url="THE URL">
```

As it's showing in a top frame, I want "THE URL" to be the URL in the address bar.  As it is, it's only "sharing" the URL of the top frame in which it resides.

Here's the example:

http://1max.us/go/test

What bit of PHP could I replace "THE URL" with that would make it pick up the whole page, not just the top frame?

Comment: javascript: document.location.href. php: $_SERVER['HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Comment: @John wouldn't he want `top.location.href` since each frame gets its own `document` object?

Comment: I tried this code: <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style " addthis:url="<? $_SERVER['HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>">  but it did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. This is what did the trick:

```
<? echo $url="".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>
```